# Count the amount of times specified numbers or words are entered

Tags: c

So an assignment says I'm supposed to write a program to print the total amount of times either a number below 18, excluding 16, is entered OR one of these words: **ABSINTH, BEER, BRANDY, CHAMPAGNE, GIN, RUM, SAKE, TEQUILA, VODKA, WHISKEY, WINE**.

For example: Input:

```
7               //specify the number of inputs
18
Vodka
16
Coke
19
17
Gin
```

Output: `3`

#### Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *p (char str[]){
    int i=0;
    while (str[i]){
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
  return str;
}
bool check(char a[]){
    int i=0;
    while (a[i]){
        if (!isdigit(a[i]))
            return false;
        i++;    
    }
    return true;
}
int main (){
    int n,t;
    int s=0;
    char a[20];
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen ("input.txt","r",stdin);
    #endif
    scanf ("%d\n",&n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        t=0;
        gets (a);
        if (check(a)){
            t = atoi (a);
            if (t<18&&t!=16)
                s++;
        }
        else if (!strcmp(p(a),"absinth")||!strcmp(p(a),"beer")||!strcmp(p(a),"brandy")||!strcmp(p(a),"champagne")||!strcmp(p(a),"gin")||!strcmp(p(a),"rum")||!strcmp(p(a),"sake")||!strcmp(p(a),"tequila")||!strcmp(p(a),"vodka")||!strcmp(p(a),"whiskey")||!strcmp(p(a),"wine"))
            s++;
    }
    printf ("%d",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is just as the assignment wants but somehow the online judge keeps telling me the code is incorrect. Can someone please tell me where I may have been wrong?

Comment: This looks more like C than C++.  Please remove tag [tag:c++] and add tag [tag:c].

Comment: Looks like you are missing some use case.

Comment: Your manual number conversion doesn't handle negatives.  Why don't you use `atoi`?  And use `tolower` instead of that wild lowercase conversion you're doing.

Comment: You are printing the number without a trailing newline.  I don't know what the online judge is looking for but I would expect a trailing newline.

Comment: what if the input is like `1ABSGDV`, you end up converting it to number !!